# Multifile uploading and redirecting

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views, multifile-uploader

I've just built a very basic multifile upload function and tested it works because after selecting for example, 2 files, they are uploaded to the `/media/` directory. I'm just a bit lost as to why on the frontend, when I click 'Choose Files' select 2 files, then 'Upload', then on the same page "No file chosen" is then given.

**models.p**y

```
class Multi_File(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

**multi_upload.py**

```
class FileFieldView(FormView):
    form_class = FileFieldForm
    uploaded_file_url = None
    template_name = 'myApp/multi_upload.html'  # To be replaced with a proper template.
    success_url = ''  # To be replaced with proper URL or reverse().

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        for file in request.FILES.getlist('myfile'):

            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(file.name, file)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')

        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                multiFile = form.save()
                data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': multiFile.file.name, 'url': multiFile.file.url}
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FileFieldView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['uploaded_file_url'] = self.uploaded_file_url
        return context
```

**multi_upload.html**

```
{% block content %}

  {% if not uploaded_file_url %}

  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile" multiple>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
  </form>

  <p>File upload location: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>

  {% else %}
    <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>

  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Also, on the same page it states "File upload location: None", directly after uploading the files.

Comment: It's not clear for your goal when you select two files in your form page:
- do you want only upload two file in media directory ?
- do you want create two instance of class Multi_File with the file ?